# Getting Error while identifying an element in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I have to select the above highlighted link `New V1 Project` but I am not able to identify the element.

I've tried using linktext function but it is giving error... can anybody help?

Hierachy is something like:-

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="40" align="center">
        <td width="5">
        <td align="center" noWrap="" style="border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;" bgColor="#cccccc">
            <a class="navSelected" onmouseover="window.status=''; return true" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true" href="index.cfm?fuseaction=project.view&version=1">
        <td width="5">
        <td width="5">
        <td align="center" noWrap="" style="border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;" bgColor="#cccccc">
            <a class="nav" onmouseover="window.status=''; return true" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true" href="index.cfm?fuseaction=project.create_form&version=1">
        <td width="5">
        <td width="5">
        <td align="center" noWrap="" style="border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;" bgColor="#cccccc">
            <a class="nav" onmouseover="window.status=''; return true" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true" href="index.cfm?fuseaction=project.create_form&version=2">
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

please see the highlighted HTML code in image... I am not sure how this `Text` element is linked with `a` tag

My Code that I've used to identify element is:

```
WebElement v1Link = driver.findElement(By.linktext("New V1 Project"));
WebElement v1Link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[3]/a[@text()= 'New v1 Project']"));
```

but none of the above 2 methods are working... please somebody help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the link by the following xpath:

```
//td/a[normalize-space(text()) = 'New V1 Project']
```

FYI, your version of xpath was almost correct:

- no need to put `@` before the `text()`
- the text is `New V1 Project`, not `New v1 Project`
- you need to use [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space)

Hope that helps.

Comment: is it a link? if yes why there isn't any closing `a` tag?

Comment: Its not working ... would it be?

`//tr/td[6]/a[normalize-space(text()) = 'New V1 Project']`
I've replaced 3 with 6.

Comment: its not working... selenium isn't able to identify this element.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //td/a[normalize-space(text()) = 'New V1 Project'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 326 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:

Comment: @pArAs ok, what about `//a[@class="nav"]`?

Comment: but then in that case it wouldn't be uniquely identified... all other elements will have same xpath `//a[@class="nav"]`

See the HTML code that I've pasted.

Comment: @pArAs yup, just want to be sure it can find the link by the class name. Let's try this `//a[@class="nav" and contains(text(), "V1")]`.

Comment: nopes didn't work.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //a[@class='nav' and contains(text(), 'V1')] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 325 milliseconds

Comment: @pArAs hm, but you do see this link in the results of the following xpath search: `//a[@class="nav"]`?

Comment: I've tried below code... but execution kind of stuck.. it didn't print anything..

  List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav']"));
  for (WebElement i:links){
   System.out.println(i);
  }

Comment: It worked... I had selected wrong window thats why it wasn't able to identify element.

Comment: @pArAs glad to hear that. Sorry, I was out of ideas. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cssselector-

```
 WebElement v1Link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.nav[href='index.cfm?fuseaction=project.create_form&version=2']"));
```

Comment: Try this - WebElement v1Link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(div>table>tbody>tr>td>table>tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)));        Make sure hierarchy from div  is correct. I am referring your image for HTML source or provide complete html from class=ext-ie part.